# How to create an unique array, based on a multidimensional array with the same "name"?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to create an unique array based on an array of products, example being:

```
$orderProducts = array (
array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 4),
array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 6),
array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 8),
array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 10),
array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 12),
array('name' => 'Series 222', 'price' => 5),
array('name' => 'Series 222', 'price' => 5),
array('name' => 'Series 1', 'price' => 7),
array('name' => 'Series 1', 'price' => 7),
);
```

The objective is to create an array with **a single name iteration**, with the sum of their prices. 
For example, all Series 101. Pure Red Sable would be 40.
Then, I'd like to put them inside a new unique array, like this:

```
$newProductsArray = array (
array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 40),
array('name' => 'Series 222', 'price' => 10),
array('name' => 'Series 1', 'price' => 14),
);
```

I'm using PHP version 5.4.12 but I've manually added the *array_column* function and experimented with it to reach my goal, with no success. Perhaps it's possible to expand the function to create the desired result?

```
function array_column($array,$column_name)
{
  return array_map(function($element) use($column_name){return  $element[$column_name];}, $array);
}
```

Comment: this should work https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Comment: Looks interesting and would work but prefer a simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `foreach` will help you out.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/782554)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$orderProducts = array(
    array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 4),
    array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 6),
    array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 8),
    array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 10),
    array('name' => 'Series 101. Pure Red Sable', 'price' => 12),
    array('name' => 'Series 222', 'price' => 5),
    array('name' => 'Series 222', 'price' => 5),
    array('name' => 'Series 1', 'price' => 7),
    array('name' => 'Series 1', 'price' => 7),
);
$result=array();
foreach($orderProducts as $value)
{
    if(!isset($result[$value["name"]]))
    {
        $result[$value["name"]]=$value;
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$value["name"]]["price"]+=$value["price"];
    }
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

**Solution 2:**

```
$result=array();
array_map(function($value) use (&$result){
    if(!isset($result[$value["name"]]))
    {
        $result[$value["name"]]=$value;
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$value["name"]]["price"]+=$value["price"];
    }
}, $orderProducts);
print_r(array_values($result));
```